# Spring Data MongoDB annotation descriptions

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-annotations

I was reading up on Spring Data MongoDB and the documentation

[Spring Data MongoDB](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/)

says that since 1.10 Spring Data MongoDB supports `@CountQuery`, `@DeleteQuery` and `@ExistQuery`. But non of the documentations explain what those annotations are for and what their functionalities are.

Could someone point to a Spring documentation with explanations on those three annotations ?

Comment: Searching the source code on GitHub is usually a good place to start [CountQuery, DeleteQuery](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/56e61a296582169c0498eda782889215500f9381/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/PersonRepository.java#L327-L344) [ExistsQuery](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/56e61a296582169c0498eda782889215500f9381/spring-data-mongodb/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/PersonRepository.java#L234-L236). The code also quotes the JIRA issues which describe them.

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation for each MongoDB repository queries on this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/)

Click on the particular query for details